ReScript test setup: Trouble opening src module
I'm new to ReScript (previously BuckleScript) and trying to create a basic project template. I'm having trouble setting up unit testing. Here is my current setup:
Folder stucture
src/Demo.res
test/Demo.test.res
rescript.json

In rescript.json I have:
{
  "sources": [
    {
      "dir": "src",
      "subdirs": true
    },
    {
      "dir": "test",
      "subdirs": true,
      "type": "dev"
    }
  ],
  // ...
}

In Demo.test.res I have:
open Demo
// ...

I'm getting the error:
The module or file Demo can't be found.
 - If it's a third-party dependency:
   - Did you add it to the "bs-dependencies" or "bs-dev-dependencies" in bsconfig.json?
 - Did you include the file's directory to the "sources" in bsconfig.json? 

From what I understand, I shouldn't have to add anything to the dependencies lists because both the src and test folders are listed as sources. Any help would be appreciated.

It turns out that the filename I chose for the test module was causing problems. Changing the test file from Demo.test.res to DemoTest.res fixed the issue and open Demo now works as expected.
I'm not sure why Demo.test.res caused this to break. I'm guessing that Demo.test.res was interpreted as another module named Demo which shadowed the other one.
